# How to create transformer Cube in Microsoft Power BI

Tags: sql, analytics, powerbi

How to create Multi dimensional transformer cube in Microsoft power BI like cognos
as mention in below link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_rUNLJAUTU&list=PL1UFrxYya46MFZ3TFPpDOzR0WVMZo91gm

Any positive response will be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did not watch the video, but you cannot create cubes in Power BI as it is a reporting tool, not an OLAP engine like Cognos Transformer.   Power BI is more equivalent to Cognos Workspace Advanced.   Microsoft SQL Server Analytical Services (SSAS) is the Microsoft OLAP engine.

You can, however, use Power BI in an in-memory ROLAP like manner over a star schema using the Matrix visualization but unless data volumes are relatively small data load times can be excessive and you may run out of RAM.   Direct queries get around the size limitation but can be slow unless you have a very powerful database server.